# Construction of future tense with 'when'

Tags: tense, future-tense

Consider this expression

> This knowledge will come handy, when I am going to go there this summer.
>
> This knowledge will come handy when I go there this summer.

I would like to know if the previous expression is correct. If yes, what is the difference between the two constructions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither expression is grammatically correct. The second is missing one word, but the first has too many words. They should both be:

> This knowledge will come **in** handy when I go there this summer.

This is idiomatic English: *to [come in handy](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/handy)* is an English idiom that means *to be useful*.