# Is present continuous with when not possible here

Tags: present-continuous

When I ... (leave) London next month I will have studied here almost a year
Why is the answer **leave** and not **am leaving**

"Am leaving" in this case expresses the future, so "am leaving" should be good,all the more that  leaving can be a process.

I don't understand why "am leaving" is not good

Comment: We can say "I am leaving London next month" to express the future. However, your sentence refers to the departure as a specific point in time, and we don't use the continuous tense in that context. It may seem illogical to you, but it's how the language works.

Comment: is it because of when that you consider  the leaving as a  specific point of time

Comment: Yves, if you don't use a question mark it isn't clear that you are asking a question! The same idea can be expressed without using 'when'. The day the speaker leaves London will be almost a year after their arrival there.

Comment: I can't explain why ***am leaving*** doesn't work in this context (it's so bad I'd guess it's ***syntactically invalid***, rather than just ***non-idiomatic***). But it's worth noting that in [this very similar context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/252679/verb-tense-after-when) you can use either Simple Present OR Present Continuous (with auxiliary TO BE): *I feel more positive when the sun ***shines / is shining.*** Why the same doesn't apply to the example here is beyond me.

Comment: See [Construction of future tense with 'when'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4472/construction-of-future-tense-with-when) and [“when you do something” or “when you are doing something”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/211252/when-you-do-something-or-when-you-are-doing-something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is honestly a tricky one to figure out. Here's the best explanation I can offer:

The use of "when" *is* the reason why "am leaving" is unnatural. We could structure the sentence as two independent clauses, and it would be perfectly acceptable:

> I am leaving London next month, and I will have studied here for almost a year.

But "am leaving" becomes unnatural when we use it inside a *subordinate clause* with "when". The simplest way I can make sense of this is that there are a couple different types of [subordinating conjunctions](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/subordinating-conjunctions/), and they like to use different tenses to express future events:

- The first group is time-related conjunctions, like *when*, *once*, *before*, *after*. Subordinate clauses using these have a bias for the simple present tense. It's natural to say, "When I leave London... once I arrive in New York... before I go to the hotel... after I eat dinner". The pattern here is that these refer to what's happening *at a specific moment in time*. (The action in every case does take time to complete, but that's not *grammatically* meaningful here.)
- The second group consists of what I'm going to call "logic-related conjunctions" (maybe there's a more formal term... I don't know). These include *because*, *hence*, *therefore*, and so on. These have a bias for the present continuous tense: "Because I am leaving London next month, I can't come to your wedding in July", or "I got a job in New York, therefore I am leaving London".
- There are also some conjunctions that can go either way... sometimes adding different shades of meaning: *as*, *unless*, *while*, *since*. Interestingly, most of these words can have time meanings or logical meanings. So, we might say, "I'll wave goodbye as I board the plane," (time meaning = simple present), and also say, "I can't come to your wedding, as I'm moving to New York." (logical meaning = present continuous).

The big exception to the first group (time-related conjunctions) is when you're *deliberately* referring to something happening *during* an event. Here the present continuous is appropriate. For example:

> When I am writing my thesis next month, I won't have time for Netflix.